# Директива ng-if angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-if="yes">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.onvisible.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Привет мир");
    </script>
</div>
```

ng-if отрабатывает и вставляет скрипты, но сами скрипты не выполняются, почему, как это переделать что бы все работало?

Comment: <div ng-if="yes">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</div>

Comment: В мире ангуляра за то, что вы делаете полагается смертная казнь.

Comment: подключайте скрипты в начале страницы